# Problems with ApplySymbologyFromLayer

Tags: symbology, arcpy

I'd like to use specific colors for my Unique Values. I tried creating another layer. choosing the colors that I want, and using the ApplySymbologyFromLayer. I also updated my new layer to make sure it was classified as Unique Values. When I refresh my map, no colors are showing up, and the wrong Value Field is appearing when I manually look at symbology. Has anyone else had this problem? I get no error messages, and when I print the valueField and the symbologyType, the correct fields appear.

Here is my code -

```
color_layer=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-6]
lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-1]
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df,lyr,color_layer,True)
lyr.symbology.valueField="color"
lyr.symbology.addAllValues()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, color_layer)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: Hi Katherine, I added a little formatting to your code, just by putting 4 spaces in front of each line... it's easier to read that way.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your script with a bit of modification:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
color_layer=layers[-1]
lyr=layers[-2]
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df,lyr,color_layer,True)
lyr.symbology.valueField="color"
lyr.symbology.addAllValues()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, color_layer)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

it works as expected. I think your issue is something to do with picking appropriate layer and/or field naming match in both layers